# How to ommit object fields from a post request in swagger

Tags: swagger

Let's say I have a user model defined with: id, first_name, last_name, created_at, and I have an object definition for it in swagger.

A POST request to create a user would expect first_name and last_name. How would I write that in swagger? Swagger expects a single object for the Should I create a new object just for the that?

Comment: did you find my answer helpful or you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
myuser:
  allOf:
  - $ref: '#/definitions/myuserbase'
  - type: object
    properties:
      id:
        description: |
          Unique identifier for the classifier.
        type: string
        example: user1
      created_at:
        description: |
          Date and time the user was created.
        type: string
        format: date-time          
    required:
      - id
```

and

```
myuserbase:
  type: object
    properties:
      first_name:
        description: |
          First name of the user
        type: string
      last_name:
        description: |
          Last name of the user
        type: string 
    required:
      - first_name
      - last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark `first_name`, `last_name` as the required fields. Here is an example:

```
required:
  - first_name
  - last_name
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L658-L660

(in other words, no need to create a separate object)

Comment: But it will still be confusing in the documentation. I'm referring more for cases where I have a user object with an "id" field that gets generated when the user is created. The post request would expect a "User" object without "id". If I mark "id" as no required, the user of the API may think "id" is optional and pass it